# word for trading for an item you do not want

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a poster listing:

- in the first column: items I have to offer
- in the middle column: items I want
- in a third (rightmost) column: items I know my friends want

The header of the first column is 'Offering', the middle header is 'Seeking'.

Is there a nice concise word for buying an item for future resale I can use for the third column?

Comment: Try *concession*.

Comment: If you are seeking items listed in both the second and third columns, why list them separately?  Do people seeing the poster need to know the difference?

Comment: @DanBron, perhaps you mean *[on commission](http://www.investorwords.com/967/commission.html)*

Comment: You might call it *speculation*. But I agree with jwpat7 they don't need to know why you want it.

Comment: I always thinking of *concession* as a third-party  business physically located on your premises, but  which is unrelated to your own business. If that doesn't work, an alternative is *consignment*.

Comment: If you're intending to imply in the third column that you may or may not be interested in the items due to the indirect nature of the desire, you may want to indicate that equivocal nature in the title, such as "Considering".

Comment: "Stockpiling" might work, given its sense of "accumulating a reserve of something," to paraphrase the Merriam-Webster definition of _stockpile_. Later on, the stockpiled material may be used, resold, or otherwise disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

*Investing* means to buy something for future resell

*brokering* / *trading* can mean to act as a middleman in a transaction

*Regifting* is trading an item that you do not wish to keep

Comment: _regifting_ only applies if you were originally given the item as a gift. So it doesn't apply if you're buying the item.

Answer (score 0):

Reselling?   It doesn't capture that is a future activity compared with the current offering and seeking but keeps the same part of speech.

Answer (score 0):

I think [trade](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trade) may fit your context both as a noun and a verb:

> - The business of buying and selling commodities, products, or services; commerce.
> - To engage in buying and selling for profit. (AHD)

Answer (score 0):

If two words would be ok, how about "also wanted?" Or perhaps "acquiring" or "collecting"?

These options convey the sense that these items in this category have a lower priority, or that your need is less pressing. They don't specify what you intend to do with the stuff, but they do leave your options open.

Answer (score 0):

As Josh61 mentioned, *trade* is the word you need. Alternatively, you can also use [barter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barter).